# Mysql execute query with on-the-fly values

Tags: mysql, dynamic

Good day,

I have a practical mysql question to which I can't find help online.

Let's say I have a simple array of values
"apple, pear, onion, ananas, banana, coconuts"

and that I would like to use mysql dynamically to, for example, sort, count or group those values.

Is it possible to do something like

```
SELECT COUNT FROM ("apple", "pear", "onion", "ananas", "banana", "coconuts")
```

? (of course I tried this and other syntaxes already, to no avail)

Basically what I'm trying to understand if it's possible to avoid creating a table for such a 'simple' task and set of values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if shorter syntax exists:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT "apple"
UNION SELECT "pear"
UNION SELECT "onion"
UNION SELECT "ananas"
UNION SELECT "banana"
UNION SELECT "coconuts" ) t
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` will be slightly longer syntax but fractionally faster performance.